# how to insert the actual or current filename (the name of the file I'm working saved in a folder) in .tex or latex document?

Tags: latex, tex

how to insert the actual or current filename (the name of the file saved in a folder) in .tex or latex document? In Writer (OpenOffice) is normal to use it in a foot or header document, but in .tex documents is there a way to do it? I need it to print it in the foot. Thanks

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com could be a better place to get an answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the currfile package.

Here is how you put the current file name generically into a document:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{currfile}

\title{Article}
\author{Author}
%\date{} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The current file is: \currfilename.\\

\end{document}
```

Here is how you put the current file name in the footer:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{currfile}

\title{Article}
\author{Author}
%\date{} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  %get rid of header
\fancyfoot[L]{\currfilename} %put current file in footer

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}% sets the current page style to 'fancy'

Your text goes here.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to get ride of the file extension, i.e. `.tex`? Thanks.

Comment: @CasperYC \currfilebase

Comment: since 2020 there are standard macros, documented in
https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex-dev/base/ltfilehook-doc.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Using footnote ...

```
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\tiny{This is the last page of \jobname.pdf}}
```